# Bluetooth low energy : Discovery modes and connection mode, Independent or dependent?

Tags: testing, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

In GAP test spec (4.1.0) there is a test case (TP/DISC/NONM/BV-02-C [Non-discoverable Mode Undirected Connectable Mode]).

Basically i need to put IUT in non-discovarable mode and non-connectable mode.
Let's see what core4.1 spec has to say:

Non-Discovarable mode:
1)Shall not set LE GENERAL and LE LIMITED Flags in ADV data.
2)A Peripheral device in the non-connectable mode may send non-connectable
undirected advertising events or scannable undirected advertising events
or may not send advertising packets.
If the Peripheral device in the non-discoverable mode sends non-connectable
advertising events or scannable undirected advertising events then it is
recommended that the Host configures the Controller as follows:
• The Host should set the advertising filter policy to either ‘process scan and
connection requests only from devices in the White List’ or ‘process scan
and connection requests from all devices’.

Undirected-Connectable mode:
The Host shall configure the Controller to send undirected connectable advertising
events.

Type of advertisement is contradictory. So what should i do for this particular test case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just read a book on BLE. It seems Discovery mode has nothing to do with type of advertisement. Discovery mode only and only depends on the flag in advertisement data. Connection mode depends on type of advertisement. 
I am not marking this as correct answer. Would like feedback from someone experienced in BLE dev/test.

Update:
Discoverable modes just define the flags in adv packet. They do not dictate any type of advertisement. Any type of advertisement which can carry advertisement data payload can be used in any discoverable mode.

Now when you advertise it has be in one of the connection mode. Connection mode defines type of advertisement and discover mode defines the flag in the advertisement data.

For example:
Peripheral = (No flag + connectable undirected mode ) and Central = (General or limited discovery procedure) then this device will not be seen by application on top of GAP central.